# How to disable samba authentication

Tags: samba

I need to create a samba share with no password authentication. Service is running now, folder is available, but only with password. Here is config

```
[global]
workgroup = workgroup
security = user

[share]
comment = share_test
path = /samba-share/share
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
public = yes

[guest]
comment = test_guest
path = /samba-share/guest
force user = nobody
force group = nogroup
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
guest account = nobody
```

How can I fix this config to disable password connection? None of this folders is available without password.
For each folder I gave 777 rights just for testing and even that didn't work

Comment: **Never** give 777 rights to folders, it could ruins your computer. You could use 770 rights for example.

Comment: @damadam these rights were given only for testing, in prodiction rights are gonna be different

Answer (score 1):

Is that your entire smb.conf or is that only the changes you made to it?

If that is your entire smb.conf you are missing a line in the **[global]** section that allows guest access:

```
map to guest = Bad User
```

A "Bad User" is one which does not have a user name entry in the samba password database like an anonymous guest user. Without that override entry in smb.conf samba defaults to `map to guest = Never` which pretty much does what it sounds like it would do. It prevents access to all guests.

Add the line in smb.conf and restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`